# Custom Input Names on Mapping Node?

Tags: node-editor

Is it possible to give the input items on a mapping node custom labels? For example, I'm creating a real starfield using an environment texture, mapping node and texture coordinates node. I want the rotation inputs currently labeled as X, Y, Z to be Latitude, Right Ascension, and Heading. This makes it easy to see which controller executes the given function. I plan on sharing the file to work with some clients that are not artists, but rather astronomers. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Troy

Answer (score 2):

It's a little awkward, but I think it's the closest you can get, at least without scripting or anything.

Use 3 Value nodes, plugged into a CombineXYZ node. Press F2 to change the node name, and then that's how it will show up in the material properties panel.

[image]

Comment: Alternatively you could put the Mapping and Combine XYZ nodes in a Group using Ctrl-G and drag the Combine X, Y, Z inputs to the Group Input node then rename them on the editor's N panel Group tab.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give them a try!